# Count a duplicate value PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value that is repeated several times :

```
     Code    |  reference
  Product1   |    lamp
  Product2   |    lamp
```

What i want is when it is duplicated it shows me like that in my table :

```
   Code       |  reference
  Product1    |     1/2
  Product2    |     2/2
```

This's my query :

```
   SELECT 

      product_list.id,
      product_list.code,
      product_list.reference

  FROM  product_list

  GROUP BY product_list.code,product_list.reference
  ORDER BY product_list.code
```

My code :

```
    <tbody>
    <?php   
        foreach ( $data_list as $q => $a ):
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><h3><?php echo $a["code"];?></h3></td>
                <td><h3><?php  echo $a["refernece"];?><h3></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: not possible with a single loop. the "total" value isn't available until AFTER you've completed your loop, which means you can't print it out DURING the loop - php cannot time travel. you'll need at least two loops (one to do  inventory, another to actually print the results).

Comment: Thank for your answer. If i use a second foreach how can i count and print my results like that?

Comment: Can you show us what your `$data_list` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), — Counts all the values of an array

For example :

```php
$array = array(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4);
$vals = array_count_values($array);
echo 'NON Duplicate Items found: '.count($vals).'<br><br>';
print_r($vals);
```

Output result:

```
NON Duplicate Items found : 7
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```